# Angular Material won't install with ng add

Tags: angular, angular-material

When I use the command ng add @angular/material as instructed on the Angular Material setup guide, It doesn't appear to have installed. I try to use the material components in app.module, but I get an error. Furthermore, the package doesn't show to be listed in the package.json file. I'm not sure what could be wrong. I get the following after adding ng add...

$ ng add @angular/material

- Determining package manager...
  i Using package manager: npm
- Searching for compatible package version...
  √ Found compatible package version: @angular/material@12.1.2.
- Loading package information from registry...
  √ Package information loaded.
  Command aborted.

Additionally, I'm also not prompted to select a theme, typography, etc.

I also have Angular 12 install if that's what's making a difference.

Answer (score 3):

```
npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk
ng add @angular/material
```

Try this commmand

Answer (score 0):

```bash
ng add @angular/material@latest
```

This command worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please note, that this answer has already been given (except for the `@latest`, which is default behavior if there are no incompatibilities).